# Get Nested Users using Recursion in C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a User class which have two attributes `UserID`, and `ParentUserID`. It implies that User have self-referential relationship. Here is the class definition:

```
public class User
{
    public User() { }
    public User(string userid, string parentuserid)
    {
        this.UserID = userid;
        this.ParentUserID = parentuserid;
    }
    public string UserID;
    public string ParentUserID;
}
```

I need to implement a method which should return list of users which exist in complete hierarchy against a UserID. I believe that code would be much simpler using Recursion, but I am not able to complete it on my own.

```
public List<User> SubUsersHierarchy(List<User> users, string userid, int currentIndex)
    {
        List<User> subUsers = new List<User>();
        if (currentIndex >= users.Count)
        { }
        else
        {

        }
        return users;
    }
```

A sample client is as follows:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
User user1 = new User("User2","User1");
User user2 = new User("User3", "User1");
User user3 = new User("User4", "User3");
User user4 = new User("User5", "User2");
users.Add(user1);
users.Add(user2);
users.Add(user3);
users.Add(user4);
List<User> subUsers = SubUsersHierarchy(users, "User1", 0);
```

The Output of above call should be:

`User2, User3, User4, User5`

Comment: `"User1"` doesn't exist in the list of users.

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Voting to close.

Comment: `List<User> subUsers = users.FindAll(u => u.ParentUserID == "User1");`

Comment: @Coder2599, what you have is an N-Ary tree.  This is where a parent node can have any number of children.  Read more here http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/15-200/lectures/specialtrees/

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, that only helps find children of "User1".  It won't find the grandchildren or further descendents of "User1".

Comment: user2023861 is correct. Above line only returns first level children only!!

Comment: Ok. I missed that part. You might consider using a tree data structure to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve my goal using following code. Figured it was not too much complicated.

```
static List<User> users = null;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        users = new List<User>();
        User user1 = new User("User2","User1");
        User user2 = new User("User3", "User1");
        User user3 = new User("User4", "User3");
        User user4 = new User("User5", "User2");
        users.Add(user1);
        users.Add(user2);
        users.Add(user3);
        users.Add(user4);

        List<User> subUsersList = new List<User>();
        SubUsersHierarchy("User1", subUsersList, 1, 10);
        foreach (User user in subUsersList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user.UserID);
        }
    }

    public static void SubUsersHierarchy(string userid, List<User> subUsersList, int currentLevel, int maxLevel)
    {
        if (currentLevel > maxLevel)
            return;
        List<User> subUsers = GetSubUsers(userid);

        if (subUsers.Count == 0)
            return;

        int index = 0;
        for (index = 0; index < subUsers.Count; index++)
        {
            User user = subUsers[index];
            subUsersList.Add(user);
            SubUsersHierarchy(user.UserID, subUsersList, currentLevel + 1, maxLevel);
        }
    }

    public static List<User> GetSubUsers(string userid)
    {
        List<User> subusers = new List<User>();
        foreach (User user in users)
        {
            if (user.ParentUserID == userid)
                subusers.Add(user);
        }
        return subusers;
    }
}
```